# How to discard upcoming messages?

Tags: winapi, window, message

So I'm using messages window for process inter-communication.

Multiple processes will send the same message to the message window when a certain event occur.

I've observed that non queued messages wait for the previous message to be returned until they get processed.

Now my question is there a way to dismiss all incoming(waiting) messages at once?

Comment: No, there is not.  Each sender will be blocked waiting for its respective message to be processed, and the receiver will only see each message one at a time. You will have to synchronize your senders so they don't send while a sender is already in process of sending. You can use a shared named kernel event/mutex/semaphore object for that sync, for instance. Lock the object with timeout before sending, and unlock when the message is processed. That way, each sender checks the state of the object before attempting to send.

Comment: simply process all mesages inside windowproc as is. this is must be and no problem here

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok but can I release all waiting mutexes at once instead?

Comment: There is only 1 mutex and 1 lock. As soon as one sender unlocks it, another sender can lock it.  Lock, send, unlock, repeat. Thus serializing the senders so the receiver gets only 1 message at a time.  If that is not what you want, then there is no point in syncing the senders at all, just let them all send at once and make your receiver handle all of the messages, like RbMn suggested. If you don't actually want to process all of the messages, you could always just set a short timer on the first message received and then ignore processing any subsequent messages until the timer elapses.

Comment: Or, if you are worried about taking a long time to process each message, and you don't want the other senders to wait, you could always pass each received message to a worker thread for processing (or ignore new messages if the thread is already busy processing), allowing you to quickly release each sender from waiting.

Answer (score 0):

One way to dismiss all waiting message is that you could get out all messages from the message queue.

```
case Repeated_Message:
        PostMessage(hWnd, Custom_Flag, 0, 0);
        while (true)
        {
            GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);
            if (msg.message == Custom_Flag)
                break;
        }
        //To Do.
        break;
```